# Defer Sending Email using Mail.app

Tags: mail.app

I'm curious, does anybody have a decent solution for sending e-mails via Mail.app at some scheduled times? I'm badly in need of something like that :)

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you don’t consider [Deferrersender (web based)](http://www.deferredsender.com/) to be decent. It’s not, but it delivers.

**UPDATE**: An alternative, that doesn’t use Mail.app (but Thunderbird) would be to use [SendLater](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/addon/4791/). An extension that does exactly that. But it’s for [Thunderbird](http://mozilla.com/thunderbird). I couldn’t find a similar plug-in for Mail.app.

Comment: Not an option ... sorry

Answer (score 1):

You can use Apple scripts to setup mail app schedule mail via iCal

http://homepage.mac.com/aamann/Mail_Scripts.html

Or use web based service as Martin said

http://www.lettermelater.com/

Comment: Tried Mail Scrips already, scheduled sending from drafts but they failed to send the e-mails... do you personally use Mail Scrips?

Comment: I dont use mailscripts, but for testing I download and test it.
It works for me.
Make sure you save message as draft

Make sure the "mailscripts" calendar has been created in iCal

Make sure you've save message as draft and schedule delivery event appears in ical "mail scripts"

Your computer need to be running when event in iCal time.
If not, messages will be sent as soon as your computer turn on next time.
Tested software:
OS Mac OS X 10.6.4
Mail app 4.3 (1081)